# Prove $|x|-|y| \le |x+y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation, absolute-value

I'm trying to prove $|x|-|y| \le |x+y|$.
I read a solution that said it follows from $|x-y| \le |x|-|y|$ that $|x|=|y-(y-x)| \le |y|+|y-x|$ so $|x|-|y| \le |x-y|$. That last step seems like a bit of a jump to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Who upvoted this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By the triangular inequality, $|a \pm b| \le |a| + |b|$. So:
$$
|x|-|y|= |x+y-y|-|y|\le |x+y|+|-y|-|y|=|x+y|.
$$

Comment: The only part I don't get here is that I know  $|x+y-y| \le |x+y|+|-y|$, so does that mean $|x+y−y|−|y|≤|x+y|+|−y|−|y|$? Is that the same reason that $5-x \ge 4-x$?.

Comment: I am pretty sure I understand now.
$$|x|=|x+y-y| \le |x+y|+|-y|$$
Then subtract $|y|$ from both sides of the inequality.

Answer (score 5):

You have $$|x| \le |y| + |x - y|,$$
so $$|x| - |y| \le |x - y|.$$
Now reverse the roles of $x$ and $y$ to obtain your conclusion.

Comment: What do you mean by reverse roles of x and y?

Comment: Swap them  to get $|y| - |x| \le |y - x| = |x - y|.$$

Comment: But $|x-y|$ doesn't equal $|x+y|$, does it?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

Just for variety, here's a different approach: the right side is nonnegative, so if the left side is negative, the claim is true. If both sides are nonnegative, then the claim is equivalent to the inequality resulting from squaring both sides: $$x^2-\left|x\right|\left|y\right|+y^2\leq x^2+y^2$$ which is trivially true.